# Location-aware hostname resolution

Tags: network, macos, macbook-pro, vpn

Here is my situation: I am running Tunnelblick on my MacBook (running Mavericks) to connect to my own VPN, which comprises several machines, both at home and at remote locations. I can of course use the VPN-internal addresses to enable communication between my MacBook and other machines but I would like to prefer local addresses for a machine, if possible.

Example:

I have a server that is running an AppleTalk daemon for Time Machine. This server is part of the VPN and as thus it’s reachable under a 10.x.x.x IP address. However, when I’m at home I would like to use the local 192.168.x.x IP address so that traffic doesn’t have to go over the internet (and my rather smallish outbound bandwidth). Currently I edit `/etc/hosts` every time I arrive at the office or at home to facilitate the switch.

Is there any way to have this switch happen automatically?

Comment: Could you use the name of the server which should be reachable by bounjour. Then bonjour should correctly resolve it. I do not know if bonjour works over a VPN

Comment: The hostname can be resolved properly in my local network. It will, however, not be resolved properly when I’m not at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) can help you.

> ControlPlane allows you to build configuration profiles, contexts in
> ControlPlane lingo, for your Mac based on where you are or what you
> are doing.
>
> ControlPlane determines where you are or what you are
> doing based on a number of available evidence sources and then
> automatically reconfigures your Mac based on your preferences.
> Evidence sources can include your current location, visible WiFi
> networks, attached USB devices, running applications and more.  You
> can even write your own evidence sources using shell scripts!